# Performance on Networks codding

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I'm trying to write my HttpServer in JAVA.

There is a simple code for creating sockets (server and client) and reading and collect information of header, once the user writing a URL.

I'm looking for a good way (performance code) that can manipulate getting/collecting of data.

In my code, which I wrote, I fill, that it seems bad.
Maybe who can help me to explain about the third level try block for writing for a good code??

For Example, I think that the `if (headerTempData.contains("\r\n\r\n")) break;` it will be to slow for streaming and collect data from connected socket, because I don't know how much headers line will be downloaded, and for all gated information it checks.

Maybe who know additional point of relevant literature (books i.e.) that can help me to understand for good performance of code for http protocols it very helps to me

Thanks!

specific try block code:

```
try (InputStream raw = socket.getInputStream()) {

    String headerTempData = "";

    // chain the InputStream to a Reader
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(raw);

    int c;
    while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
        headerTempData += (char) c;
        System.out.print((char) c);

        if (headerTempData.contains("\r\n\r\n"))
            break;
    }

    System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - - - - EOL - - - - - - - - - - - -");

}
```

All code example:

```
package pk7HttpServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by Morris on 08/10/16.
 */
public class HTTPServer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new HTTPServer().startServer();
    }

    public void startServer() {

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080)) {

            System.out.println("Server is started");

            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                try {
                    try (InputStream raw = socket.getInputStream()) {

                        String headerTempData = "";

                        // chain the InputStream to a Reader
                        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(raw);

                        int c;
                        while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                            headerTempData += (char) c;
                            System.out.print((char) c);

                            if (headerTempData.contains("\r\n\r\n"))
                                break;
                        }

                        System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - - - - EOL - - - - - - - - - - - -");

                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    System.err.println(socket.getLocalAddress() + " is not a parseable URL");

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("error# " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it yet? What makes you think your way is inefficient? This sounds like premature optimization, which is a candidate for wasting time. Focus on optimizing when you know for sure there is an efficiency problem.

Comment: Is this for a class or to solve a real problem?

Comment: A server usually should serve many clients. Therefore you should pass the socket which you receive from serverSocket.accept() to an own thread which serves this one request. The main thred goes back to accept() for beeing ready for the next request of another client.

Comment: @chrylis   -    At this moment, this is a problem for the specific class and some additional lite classes that will working with jdbc, xml and angularjs with a parallel-way for get/delete/update any data. But, In the future, it will be grow and I re-construct the project, therefore I think build modularize project. If I will to need improve the specific classes it not be hardly for me and I didn't know at this time. then it relevant for my lite project that I want to build )). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your parse logic has several drawbacks.

1. The sender might transfer the data in chunks. This means it could be that the read() returns -1 although the whole input is not yet received. You have to implement logic to re-enter the read() if the expected end of the data has not been reached yet.
2. Transforming each byte to a char (you didn't provide the characterset to be used, so your code behaves differently on windows and linux machines) is a timeconsuming operation. So you call contains() (which is another time consuming operation) on each byte you receive.
3. I suggest to read the incoming data in blocks (e.g. 1024 bytes), aggregate it and only if you think there are now enough data received transform the byte array to a string, using a defined CharacterSet.
4. \r\n is the line break on windows. On other platforms this is different.
5. As long the received data is smaller than the length of your contains-call it never can be true. Check for the header end only if you have enough data received.

Comment: I knew that something bad in my code. Thanks for the detailed answer.